# bash + image-magick: if condition inside the program call

Tags: bash, if-statement, imagemagick

My bash script calls convert utility of the Image-magic to stack together several types of the input images depending on the provided condition:

```
if [ "$DETAILS" == 1 ]; then
#stack 3 types of images in vertical row
convert \( "${output}/${target}*.png" -bordercolor lightgoldenrod2 -border 0x2 -append \) \( "${output}/${dist}*.png" -bordercolor lightgoldenrod2 -border 0x2 -append \) \( "${output}/${angl}*.png" -bordercolor lightgoldenrod2 -border 0x2 -append \) -bordercolor lightgoldenrod2 -border 2x0 +append -background white -alpha deactivate ${output}/HBONDS-summary.png
else
   #stack 1 type of images in vertical row
convert \( "${output}/${target}*.png" -bordercolor lightgoldenrod2 -border 0x2 -append \) -bordercolor lightgoldenrod2 -border 2x0 +append -background white -alpha deactivate ${output}/HBONDS-summary.png
fi
```

Since the difference between two options is just the number of the blocks

```
\( .. \)
```

provided for convert, would it be possible rather to put the IF condition INSIDE the convert to simplify the script e.g. this could be a wrong bash syntax but the general idea may be:

```
 # Add two more blocks with ${dist} and ${angl} images if we match the condition:
convert \( "${output}/${target}*.png" -bordercolor lightgoldenrod2 -border 0x2 -append \) **!NB >>> if [ "$DETAILS" == 1 ];** then \( "${output}/${dist}*.png" -bordercolor lightgoldenrod2 -border 0x2 -append \) \( "${output}/${angl}*.png" **fi;** <<< -bordercolor lightgoldenrod2 -border 0x2 -append \) -bordercolor lightgoldenrod2 -border 2x0 +append -background white -alpha deactivate ${output}/HBONDS-summary.png
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
convert_extra_args=()
if [ "$DETAILS" == 1 ]; then
  convert_extra_args=(
    \( "${output}/${dist}*.png" -bordercolor lightgoldenrod2 -border 0x2 -append \)
    \( "${output}/${angl}*.png" -bordercolor lightgoldenrod2 -border 0x2 -append \)
  )
fi

convert \( "${output}/${target}*.png" -bordercolor lightgoldenrod2 -border 0x2 -append \) "${convert_extra_args[@]}" -bordercolor lightgoldenrod2 -border 2x0 +append -background white -alpha deactivate ${output}/HBONDS-summary.png
```

Answer (score 1):

@oguzismail's solution is probably neater for building up a complex set of options, and for ease of quoting, but I just wanted to show another couple of possibilities. Note that these are `bash-isms`, i.e. specific to bash-like shells.

---

Output red box, but add blue box if DETAILS is 1:

```
DETAILS=0
magick -size 100x100 xc:red $( [ $DETAILS -eq 1 ] && echo "xc:blue +append" ) result.png
```

[image]

and:

```
DETAILS=1
magick -size 100x100 xc:red $( [ $DETAILS -eq 1 ] && echo "xc:blue +append" ) result.png
```

[image]

---

Another possibility:

```
DETAILS=""
printf "$DETAILS" | magick -size 100x100 xc:red $(cat) result.png
```

[image]

and:

```
DETAILS="xc:blue xc:yellow +append"
printf "$DETAILS" | magick -size 100x100 xc:red $(cat) result.png
```

[image]